# "But in a city where people are used to cold winters, life carries on as usual."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> But in a city where people **are used to** cold winters, life carries on as usual.

Although I can't clearly comprehend this construction, I understand it intuitively, but I want to read something about the rule, so give me something about it, please, if you can.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20to There is no particular rule, it's just a common phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a few similar examples from the internet:

> - *But in a time where our mental health is being challenged daily, the question “How are you?” may be too stale.*

[Today.com; 2020]

> - ... *but in a time where stone, and not paper, was the writing material of choice, the straight, simple lines of a runic alphabet
>   were by far the easiest form of record* ....

[[Joanne Harris; Runes](http://www.joanne-harris.co.uk/v3site/books/runemarks/runes.html)

> - *But in a country where we have had parliamentary democracy, uninterrupted by invasion, revolution, or tyranny for over 300 years,
>   it is difficult to strike a real chord with most people outside the
>   legal world when talking about the rule of law.*

[[UK Supreme Court](https://www.supremecourt.uk/docs/speech-131015.pdf)]

> - *But in a situation where we must provide both modes of instruction simultaneously, this is just not feasible at this time.*

[[Tuscaloosa CSS](https://www.tcss.net/cms/lib/AL01001644/Centricity/Domain/6160/EDGENUITY%20FAQs.pdf)]

Each paraphrases as 'But in a state / place / time where A is true, B is the case.'

The usual thrust is that B *must necessarily (or very likely) be the case* as a consequence of A obtaining. This is certainly true in the above four examples. But the example in the question is the subtler reading:

But **in spite of A being true**, B is nevertheless the case.

The use of 'be used to' (= be accustomed to, with the implication of being able to handle) can be easily looked up in any reasonable dictionary.